# adLdap Integration Laravel - forbidden 403 nginx on trying to access login page

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to implement the following login: "https://www.exchangecore.com/blog/using-ldap-active-directory-authentication-php"

I configured the script to use Laravel eloquent on controller. With adserver and ldaprn I created routes for showlogin form and login post(submit) I altered on .env to the app URL of the app, and on config.app. Now when I try to access the root file "/" it says forbidden error code 403 nginx, and for example if I have on root directory a file of php or html it reads, seems to can't enter the app of my Laravel and go to / on login

```
class LdapAuthController extends Controller
{
    public function ldapLogin(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
            // LDAP authentication logic
            if (isset($request->username) && isset($request->password)) {
                $adServer = "ldap://domaincontroller.mydomain.com";
                $ldap = ldap_connect($adServer);
                $username = $request->username;
                $password = $request->password;
                $ldaprdn = 'mydomain' . "\\" . $username;
                ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
                ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
                $bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldaprdn, $password);

                if ($bind) {
                    // LDAP authentication successful
                    $filter = "(sAMAccountName=$username)";
                    $result = ldap_search($ldap, "dc=MYDOMAIN,dc=COM", $filter);
                    if ($result) {
                        // Retrieve user's email from LDAP
                        $info = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
                        $email = $info[0]["mail"][0]; // Assuming email is stored in 'mail' attribute

                        // Retrieve user's role from the user_roles table
                        $userRole = UserRole::where('email', $email)->first();

                        // If user role found, assign it to the user
                        if ($userRole) {
                            $role = $userRole->role;
                            // Here you can do something with the user's role, like storing it in a session or a cookie
                            session(['user_role' => $role]);
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Handle the case when ldap_search returns false
                        return back()->with('error', 'LDAP search failed');
                    }

                    @ldap_close($ldap);
                    // Redirect or do something upon successful login
                    return redirect()->route('dashboard');
                } else {
                    // Invalid credentials
                    return back()->with('error', 'Invalid email address / password');
                }
            }
        } else {
            return view('auth.login');
        }
    }
}
```

I also changed in the .env file the name of the real adserver and placed it on the above code with all configurations, I changed on config.app  'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://domaincontroller.mydomain.com and secure protocol to false, created a userRole table to match the login with the email and do inside validation on who ever enters which pages, on web.php:

```
    Route::get('/login', function () {
        return view('auth.ldap-login-form');
    })->name('login');
    
    Route::post('/login', [LdapAuthController::class, 'ldapLogin'])->name('login.submit');
    
    Route::group(['namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers'], function () {
    
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['guest']], function () {
            Route::post('/ldap-login', [LdapAuthController::class, 'ldapLogin'])->name('ldap-login');
        });
    
        Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
            Route::get('/logout', 'LogoutController@logout')->name('logout.logout');
    
    
            // Admin routes
            Route::group(['middleware' => ['checkUserRole:admin']], function () {
```

and on my config auth.php:

```
 'guards' => [
            'web' => [
                'driver' => 'session',
                'provider' => 'users',
            ],
        ],
    
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | User Providers
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |
        | All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
        | users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
        | mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
        |
        | If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
        | sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
        | be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
        |
        | Supported: "database", "eloquent"
        |
        */
    
        'providers' => [
            'users' => [
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => App\Models\UserRole::class,
            ],
    
            // 'users' => [
            //     'driver' => 'database',
            //     'table' => 'users',
            // ],enter code here
        ],
```

I'm getting forbidden nginx on trying to access the domain on /
when I have for example a home.html page on the root folder of the project I can see it, but if I remove it I get forbidden nginx 403

Comment: This is not Laravel code, it looks like something from the dark days of PHP 4.3. If you're not able to integrate LDAP authentication properly into Laravel with guards and providers, just install a package that does, like [this one](https://github.com/DirectoryTree/LdapRecord-Laravel).

Comment: my bad i placed on the code the version from the website exchangecore, now i edited my post to use the laravel eloquent im trying

Comment: This is still not good. Why are you checking for request properties instead of doing proper validation? Why are things like your LDAP server and base DN not in a configuration file? Why does a table of user roles have an email column? You also aren't doing any authentication here, nor are you returning a 403 error anywhere.

Comment: If it was good i wouldnt be asking, i can't find much information about this on internet other then installing ldaprecord, and i already setup the config.app url to be the correct one, secure_protocol : false because its http for start and .env also the app_url to be that one as well, and the server configurations of adldap and ldaprn to use the correct naming, then setup the userrole table because i cant access have permissions to the users table i have to match the emails of logins and on routes and blade i setup the permissions inside on whoever can access each page, web.php got the groups

Comment: i edited my question please if someone could help clarify what's the issue

Comment: I will point out, once again, that you are not authenticating a user anywhere in your code. All you are doing is setting a session variable.